# Getting "Permission denied" errors from efibootmgr

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

Well, im a new linux user, i recently made a dual boot (between Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu) but when I restarted the PC I saw BIOS POST screen (you know, that screen with "press  to enter boot, press  to choose a boot device"). It started with the GNU GRUB boot loader (or something like that).

There are options in GRUB to boot Ubuntu or choose from advanced options, and Windows does show up. The problem: I can't select an option because my keyboard doesn't work. I have tried everything that I can find and it doesn't work. The closest I've gotten is using something called "EFIBOOTMNG" that can set priority or an order of the bootloaders, but when i input

```
ochipi@Ubuntu-Phoenix:~$ efibootmgr
```

I get this:

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0006,0002,0003,0004,0005
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell 
Boot0003* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive
Boot0004* UEFI:Removable Device
Boot0005* UEFI:Network Device
Boot0006* ubuntu
```

I put this in to change the order:

```
ochipi@Ubuntu-Phoenix:~$ efibootmgr -o 0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006
```

(I'm trying to set the priority to the Windows Boot manager)

But I get this error:

```
efibootmgr: Could not remove entry from BootOrder: Permission denied
```

So... what should I do? I want to use Windows too. I cant set anything in the UEFI BIOS (or firmware, as Windows likes to call it :P)

I have an MSI h81m e-33 that (as I know) does not have a key to enter the BIOS setup.

I don't want to format my PC, because I have too much important things on it. Can anyone help me to set the Windows Boot Manager as the "default" or favorite boot manager (and not GRUB)?

Comment: Let me warn you that, if you set Windows as the default bootloader, you won't be able to boot into Ubuntu anymore. If that's what you want, however, putting `sudo` before `efibootmgr` (so `sudo efibootmgr`) will let you run it. Please don't do this, though, as it would be better to get GRUB working so you can have a successful dual-boot.

Comment: Now, it seems that your keyboard works in Ubuntu, but not in GRUB. Shut down your computer and turn it on, but instantly hold down `delete`. See if you get into the BIOS setup. If not, it's possible there's something weird with the connection of the keyboard. Try another port (if this is a desktop) or try another keyboard.

Comment: You can change the boot loader used for the next boot *only* with the `-n` option to `efibootmgr`, as in `sudo efibootmgr -n 0000` to boot into Windows next time, but leave the regular boot order unchanged so that Ubuntu should remain bootable after that one-time Windows boot.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to run `efibootmgr` with `sudo`, so that it has permission to update the firmware settings. Try:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006
```